# console.log not printing in chrome extension pop up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

manifest.json:

```
"browser_action":{
"default_icon":"icon.png",
"default_popup":"opennotes.html"
}
```

HTML:"opennotes.html"

```
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Hello World</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
               $(document).ready(function () {
                   console.log("started");
                });
            </script>
          </head>
        <body>
                    <h1>First Extension Example</h1>
                    <p>console not working</p>    
        </body>
     </html>
```

i'm trying to print in the console but it is not working. when i try opening "opennotes.html" separately it is working.

PS:i have tried previous answers but none worked for me.

Comment: In addition to the answer below: inline code won't work. Use a separate js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

click the extension icon then open the Console terminal of the popup page(not the Console terminal of current webpage).If you want to complete your chrome extension，you should add `content_scripts` and `permission` configure in your `manifest.json` file.